# Skimage imread returns img_arrayndarray; what are the properties?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, scikit-image, vision

Really surprised but I cannot find any documentation on `img_arrayndarray` which is what skimage's imread returns.

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread

My primary question is what properties/methods etc. this object has.

Alternatively, is there a reason the documentation is so lacking? For example is it common practice to just turn the imread into a numpy array? Thanks

Comment: It's a bug that's been fixed already, that happened because `imread` now returns their own object instead of a numpy array.  Call `np.asarray` on the result to get a standard NumPy array, or use `io.imread(..., plugin='matplotlib')` or `io.imread(..., plugin='pil')` for now to avoid the issue.  This will be fixed in the next point release.

Comment: Thanks, so does your answer disagree with the below one? i.e. `imread` does NOT return a standard np array?

Comment: I think Stéfan misread your question and got confused with a different bug. imread should return a standard numpy ndarray. The formatting error is due to a recent sphinx or numpydoc formatting bug. As warped points out in his answer, it's actually `img_array : ndarray`, with `ndarray` referring to `numpy.ndarray`. See this page in the docs for how to use them: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html and see the NumPy documentation for more about NumPy arrays: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/

Answer (score 2):

Testing the function, 
using Python 2.7.13, Ipython 5.1.0, skimage 0.13.0, 
and Python 3.6.7, Ipython 7.4.0, skimage 0.15.0:

> ```
>  In [1]: from skimage import io
>
>  In [2]: a = io.imread('testimg.tif')
>
>  In [3]: type(a)  
>  Out[3]: numpy.ndarray
> ```

your link to the documentation is skimage 0.16.0, but I think it is safe to assume that there simply is a typo in the documentation.

edit: also, looking at the [source](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/io/_io.py#L14):

> ```
> def imread(fname, as_gray=False, plugin=None, flatten=None,
>            **plugin_args):
>     """Load an image from file.
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     fname : string
>         Image file name, e.g. ``test.jpg`` or URL.
>     as_gray : bool, optional
>         If True, convert color images to gray-scale (64-bit floats).
>         Images that are already in gray-scale format are not converted.
>     plugin : str, optional
>         Name of plugin to use.  By default, the different plugins are
>         tried (starting with imageio) until a suitable
>         candidate is found.  If not given and fname is a tiff file, the
>         tifffile plugin will be used.
>     Other Parameters
>     ----------------
>     plugin_args : keywords
>         Passed to the given plugin.
>     flatten : bool
>         Backward compatible keyword, superseded by `as_gray`.
>     Returns
>     -------
>     img_array : ndarray
>         The different color bands/channels are stored in the
>         third dimension, such that a gray-image is MxN, an
>         RGB-image MxNx3 and an RGBA-image MxNx4.
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I also had an issue where I tried using `ndims` instead of `ndim` (the correct np), hence leading to this question. I will accept this answer pending the follow-up in the comment above

Answer (score 1):

A bit more details to [Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976670/skimage-imread-returns-img-arrayndarray-what-are-the-properties#comment98607523_55976670):

`scikit-image` doesn't internally implements IO capabilities, but rather wraps and delegates them to external libraries (referred to as ["plugings"](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/plugins.html)).

One can see the supported plugins here - https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html, and the plugins available for his or her own environment by making a call to [skimage.io.find_available_plugins](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.find_available_plugins).
The plugins are loaded following a specific [priority list](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.plugin_order).

The issue you are seeing is related to the error in dtype validation in one of the plugins. Recently, a similar bug has been fixed for `imageio` plugin (https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/3837) and it will be incorporated into 0.14.3 (LTS), 0.15.1/0.16 (latest) releases.